# Configuração do Angular.js não funcionando

Tags: angularjs

Já varri a internet buscando uma solução, mas de forma alguma o *angular* funciona em meu projeto. No projeto em qual eu quero utiliza-lo existi muitas importações javascript não sei se isso pode ser o problema, mas abaixo eu ilustro como eu estou configurando ele.

```
<html ng-app="jooceBox">
    <head ng-app="jooceBox">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>JooceBox v1.0</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <!-- Le styles -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
        <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/wizard/lib/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- Arquivo que contem as diretrizes do Angular -->
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/js/app-crm/service.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Pulando o codigo -->

            <div ng-controller="StoreController">
                <p>{{greeting.text}}, world </p>
            </div>

    <!-- Pulando o codigo -->

    </head>
```

**service.js**

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('jooceBox', ['ngRoute','ngResource']);

    app.controller('StoreController', function($scope,$resource) {
        $scope.greeting = { text: 'Hello' };
    });

    var gem = {
        name : 'Azurite',
        price : 110.50,
        canPurchase : false,
        soldOut : false
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Seu código não menciona a biblioteca básica do Angular. Tente adicionar a seguinte linha (antes de `angular-resource`):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
```